# "Module not found" error in node.js while importing Python API

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, import, module

I am creating a React app and following directions to implement popular times data using this API: 
https://github.com/m-wrzr/populartimes

Per the directions, I was able to successfully clone and pip install the repository requirements. But, when I tried to run the file with the following lines of code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import populartimes from './populartimes/populartimes/';
```

I get a "module not found" error. For context, the populartimes folder is located in the same directory as the file we are working on. Also, populartimes/populartimes/ contains two python files (**init** and crawler)

Comment: Are you trying to import a Python module from Javascript?

Comment: Yes. In addition, once that module is loaded we should be able to call the relevant function in JS i.e. populartimes.get_id(...). Thanks for the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "we should be able to..."? It is not possible to (well, at least not that easily) import Python modules inside Javascript. Try finding an `npm` module that has similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly use Python Code/Library into JavaScript. To implement this API either:

1. Use the JS library for this API. Quick Google Search provided me this library [@christophern/populartimesjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@christophern/populartimesjs)
2. Implement a python backend and use your desired python library there.